# How to solve by approximation linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have a set with 10.000 equations like this below:

```
1*A1 + 1*A2 + 0*A3 + 0*A4 + 1*A5... 1*A800 = 1
0*A1 + 1*A2 + 1*A3 + 0*A4 + 0*A5... 0*A800 = 0
0*A1 + 0*A2 + 0*A3 + 1*A4 + 1*A5... 0*A800 = 1
0*A1 + 1*A2 + 1*A3 + 0*A4 + 1*A5... 1*A800 = 0
```

I need to find a solution to all A1, A2...A800 constants BUT there will be never an exact solution because of how the data above was colected (they are like probabilities, also **the number of equations will always be much larger than the number of constants**, so the chance of an exact solution is pretty low), I need an aproximated solution which should be `optimal` in such a way that if I replace the solution of all constants back to the equation above, the `error` (expected result - actual result) is the minimum.

So how is the logic behind this solution? After knowing the logic, I will program it in C++ to solve the equations or, if there is a better way of doing this in Excel, that would be nice too. I am a Mechanical Engineer and Programmer, and even having some knowledge on solving liner equations, finding optiminal solutions and such, I cant find a way out of this problem!

NOTE: all A1, A2... A800 must be always positive!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to solve overdetermined system is by least-squares. If your system is

$$Ax=b,$$ you form the so-called *normal equations*,

$$A^TAx=A^Tb$$ which form a square system (in your case $800\times800$, dense). You will obtain a solution that is optimal in the least-squares sense (minimum sum of the squared residues).

Anyway, due to the special form of the coefficients, maybe some other approach is better.

---

**Update:**

The last minute note (positiveness constraint) makes it a quite different and much harder problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares

Comment: This is a constrained problem.

Comment: @Chrystomath: this was missing.

Comment: I know. I was writing the same answer.

Comment: I thought I knew math untill you replied me! I only understood the first part Ax=b but didnt understand the remaining. How the square system would help me? Also, is my system of Ax=b? It's linear, but I dont know if it is like Ax=b

Comment: @Samul: hem, *any* linear system has the form $Ax=b$. This is the most general.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. I watched 2 videos on Youtube about LOS and read a little bit about it since your answer, but I still cant understand how that helps me solve my problem cause I dont understand how to transform Ax1 + Bx2 + Cx3... = y into y = A + bx (linear form).

Comment: @Samul: if you can't make the difference between $Ax=b$ and $y=A+bx$ (which is meaningless), I am not surprised that you don't understand my answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure what you pointed me, does not help at all. So far, the best I came was this https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/36-3/tang.pdf This PDF explains how to do EXACTLY what I want, but it assumes some things that I think are incompatible with my case.

Comment: @Samul: good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot about the subject, I came to the conclusion that regression linear would not solve this specific problem using OLS (at least not computationaly efficient), for example.

The best method I found is using iterative method and choose a method that converges. I found that the The Jacobi Method works pretty well for solving a set of linear equations. And a "plus" side of Jacoby Method is that you can "choose" how long you wanna run the algorithm according to how satisfied you are with the results. If you reach a point where the `error` of the tried values is getting enoughly small, then you can stop!

source: https://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/5e/students/ch08-10/chap_10_2.pdf

For those who cant program, here is a pretty straighforward video showing how to do that using only excel -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW0lm4O3Ptw